# Regex para extrair endereço de email de uma string

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tentando fazer um regex para que pegue apenas o valor entre `<` e `>`.

Porém estou tendo bastante dificuldade.

Segue um exemplo:

```
teste <testes@gmail.com>
```

Regex que tentei criar:

```
/[^\w][\w@\w]+/g
```

Porém ao tentar pegar o valor ele me retorna o sinal de menor.

Answer (score 11):

Uma expressão entre colchetes representa uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Por exemplo, `[abc]` significa "a letra **a**, ou a letra **b** ou a letra **c**" (apenas uma delas).

Se retirar os colchetes (`abc`) aí significa "a letra **a** seguida da letra **b**, seguida da letra **c**" (as 3 letras nesta ordem).

E se tiver um `^` dentro dos colchetes, significa que está negando o que tem dentro. Ou seja, `[^abc]` significa "qualquer coisa que não seja a letra **a**, nem a letra **b**, nem a letra **c**".

Já `\w` [é um atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) para `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, ou seja, "qualquer letra maiúscula, minúscula, dígitos ou `_`".

Portanto, `[^\w]` significa "qualquer caractere que não seja `\w`", e por isso que a expressão está pegando também o caractere `<` ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/Bokh95/1) um exemplo desta regex funcionando).

E `[\w@\w]` seria "um `\w`, ou o caractere `@` ou um `\w`". Pois é, o `\w` aparece duas vezes dentro dos colchetes, o que é redundante.

No seu caso específico você só quer o que está `<` e `>`, então você poderia usar apenas os próprios caracteres `<` e `>`. Não precisa usar `\w`, pois você já sabe exatamente quais são os delimitadores (`<` e `>`), então use especificamente estes caracteres.

Entre eles você poderia usar `.+` que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere". `.*` também funcionaria, mas o `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências", o que faria aceitar a string `<>`.

Então a regex ficaria `<(.+)>`:

- `<` e `>` representam os próprios caracteres `<` e `>`
- `.+` é "uma ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere"
- os parênteses servem para definir um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), para que seja possível obter o trecho correspondente com o método [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

O código fica assim:

```js
let texto = "teste <testes@gmail.com>";
let email = texto.match(/<(.+)>/)[1];
console.log(email);
```

---

### Ganância

O problema dos quantificadores `+` e `*` é que [eles são gananciosos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) e tentam pegar o maior número possível de caracteres. No seu caso específico não faz diferença, mas caso você tenha mais de um par de `<` e `>`, o resultado pode ser inesperado:

```js
let texto = "teste <testes@gmail.com> outro <outro@mail.com>";
let email = texto.match(/<(.+)>/)[1];
console.log(email); // testes@gmail.com> outro <outro@mail.com
```

O trecho capturado será `testes@gmail.com> outro <outro@mail.com`: o quantificador `+` pega o maior trecho possível que satisfaça a regex. Como eu usei `.+`, ele vai pegar a maior quantidade possível de qualquer caractere, até achar um `>` (ele acha o primeiro, mas como tem outro depois, ele continua). Por isso ele acaba pegando mais do que "devia".

Neste caso, basta [cancelar a ganância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) colocando um `?` na frente:

```js
let texto = "teste <testes@gmail.com> outro <outro@mail.com>";
let email = texto.match(/<(.+?)>/)[1];
console.log(email); // testes@gmail.com
```

Com isso, o email capturado passa a ser somente "testes@gmail.com".

---

#### Sobre o uso de regex para validar emails

Mas se entre `<` e `>` sempre vai ter um email, talvez a regex deva ser mais específica, assim você evita os "falso-positivos" (obter uma string que está entre `<` e `>` mas não é um email). Só que aí ela começa a ficar complicada demais (veja [este exemplo](https://regex101.com/library/zY0sV2), só para ter uma ideia). Mas pelo menos você garante que só vai ter dados válidos (evitando strings como `"<123>"` - supondo que você só vai aceitar endereços de email).

Só precisa ver se vale a pena ter uma regex tão complexa (pense na manutenção futura deste código). Quem sabe uma alternativa seja ter algo intermediário, como `<([^<>]+)>` (`<`, seguido de uma ou mais ocorrências de qualquer coisa que não seja `<` nem `>`, seguido de `>`).

Ou até mesmo uma regex mais "ingênua", como `<([\w.-]+@[a-z.]+)>` (uma ou mais ocorrências de `\w`, ponto ou traço, seguido de `@`, seguido de uma ou mais ocorrências de letras ou ponto) - ela aceita endereços de email, mas também aceita coisas como `<.@gmail.>`. Mas pelo menos não aceita `<123>` (que é algo que `.+` aceitaria, por exemplo).

Enfim, não tem muito jeito, quanto mais específica, menor a chance de falsos-positivos, mas maior a complexidade.

---

PS: Eu também comento mais sobre o uso de regex para validar emails [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348859/112052), e [nesta outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340617/112052) também.

Comment: Depois de ler isso, eu cheguei à conclusão de que não sei nada de regex. :)

Comment: @sam Quanto mais eu estudo regex, mais eu chego à mesma conclusão que vc (que eu não sei nada). Parece um assunto sem fim...

Comment: Pois é cara. Parece uma linguagem de programação própria.

Answer (score 3):

Se apenas pretende capturar o que está dentro de `<` e `>` então pode utilizar uma regex simples como:

```
<(.*)>
```

Explicação:

```
<    - caratere menor
(*.) - tudo o que está no meio como primeiro grupo de captura
>    - caratere maior
```

[Veja esta regex no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2X3LD6/1/)

Para obter o resultado do primeiro grupo de captura pode utilizar a função [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) e aceder à posição `1`:

```js
let texto = "teste <testes@gmail.com>";
let email = texto.match(/<(.*)>/)[1];
console.log(email);
```