# Dúvida funcionalidade Regex - Java

Tags: java, regex

Alguém poderia me explicar o que esse Regex permite?

```
private static final String MAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
```

Comment: Alguns sites como [Regexr](https://regexr.com/) e [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) explicam todos os componentes de uma expressão regular e ainda permitem que você as teste online

Comment: Talvez sua pergunta esteja muito ampla. Sugiro dar uma olhada em tutoriais como [este](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) e [este](http://rexegg.com/). Em seguida você pode **[edit]** sua pergunta para que ela fique mais específica sobre algum ponto em particular no qual você ficou em dúvida.

Comment: @hkotsubo minha pergunta está ampla? Eu quero saber o que esse Regex acima faz.

Comment: Repare que eu escrevi "*Talvez*". Ainda estou em dúvida, pois inicialmente pensei que precisaria escrever um tutorial de regex para responder adequadamente (e por isso ela é considerada ampla, não pq está perguntando várias coisas, mas pq a resposta ficaria longa demais). Mas talvez dê para fazer uma resposta não tão longa, ainda vou ver isso mais tarde (se ninguém responder antes, claro). De qualquer forma, se vc puder ler os links que eu e o Leonardo colocamos, talvez vc consiga entender o básico e focar suas dúvidas em pontos mais específicos. Isso ajuda a deixá-la "menos ampla"

Comment: Com certeza, fico muito agradecido pela força @hkotsubo! Abraços grande.

Comment: No fim, achei que valia a pena postar uma resposta. Mesmo tendo ficado bem grande, está bem focada na sua regex e no seu uso para validar emails (não ficou um tutorial de regex, até pq vc está usando poucos recursos da sintaxe), e no fundo o que importa [não é o tamanho da resposta, e sim o foco](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4801/112052), então acho que me equivoquei ao consider a pergunta "ampla demais". Divirta-se e bem vindo ao estranho/maravilhoso mundo das expressões regulares :-)

Comment: Apenas complementando, [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348859/112052) coloquei umas expressões (bem complicadas) para validar emails - não testei com Java, somente com JavaScript, mas não deve ser "difícil" adaptá-las, eu acho :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente, esta regex verifica se uma `String` corresponde a um endereço de email. Mas ela também pode acabar aceitando coisas "estranhas" (mais sobre isso no final).

## Analisando a regex em detalhes:

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

`^` e `$` são [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) que significam, respectivamente, o início e fim da string. Com isso você garante que a string só terá o que está na regex (sem esses marcadores, é possível verificar se somente parte da string corresponde à regex).

Os colchetes (`[]`) definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): eles servem para indicar que você quer qualquer caractere que esteja dentro deles. Por exemplo, `[abc]` significa "a letra `a` **ou** a letra `b` **ou** a letra `c`" (**apenas uma delas**, qualquer uma serve).

Só que dentro dos colchetes você pode usar alguns atalhos, como `A-Z`, que significa "letras de `A` a `Z`" (maiúsculas). De modo similar, `a-z` significa "letras minúsculas de `a` a `z`" e `0-9` significa "dígitos de `0` a `9`".

Ou seja, `[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]` significa "o caractere `_` **ou** letras (maiúsculas ou minúsculas) **ou** dígitos **ou** hífen (`-`) **ou** o sinal de mais (`+`)". As duas barras invertidas seriam para escapar o `+`, mas creio que dentro dos colchetes não seja necessário. Nos meus testes não fez diferença, mas de qualquer modo, deixei assim mesmo (*a sintaxe de regex diz que apenas um `\` é usado para escape, mas como estamos dentro de uma `String`, precisamos colocar `\\`*).

O detalhe é que "qualquer coisa dentro de colchetes" é uma expressão que corresponde a apenas **um** caractere. Se você quiser mais ocorrências, deve usar os [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), e foi isso que fizemos colocando um `+` depois dos colchetes:

```
[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+
                ^
```

Fora dos colchetes, o `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências" do que está imediatamente antes dele. No caso, é uma ou mais ocorrências de "caractere `_` **ou** letras (maiúsculas ou minúsculas) **ou** dígitos **ou** hífen (`-`) **ou** o sinal de mais (`+`)". Ou seja, strings como `abc`, `A124_fadfd-a12` e até mesmo `+_a` são consideradas válidas por esta expressão.

---

Em seguida temos `(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*`. Vamos começar com o que está dentro dos parênteses:

- `\\.`: corresponde ao caractere ponto (`.`). Está escapado com barra invertida porque o ponto tem significado especial em regex (significa "qualquer caractere"). Usando a barra invertida, ele "perde seus poderes" e vira um caractere comum
- `[_A-Za-z0-9-]+`: similar ao caso anterior, é uma ou mais ocorrências de `_`, ou letras, ou números, ou hífen

Juntas, essas 2 partes acima são "um ponto, seguido de uma ou mais letras/números/hífens/*underlines*".

Só que tudo isso está entre parênteses, e logo depois tem um `*`. Isso quer dizer "**zero** ou mais ocorrências do que está dentro dos parênteses". Ou seja, essa sequência "um ponto, seguido de uma ou mais letras/números/hífens/*underlines*" pode ocorrer várias vezes (ou nenhuma). Podemos ter strings como `.abc.cde123.fgh` ou simplesmente não ter nada.

Juntando isso com a expressão anterior, temos a primeira parte do email (antes do `@`), que pode ser desde um *username* comum (como `joaosilva`) até coisas mais complicadas como `32teste.abd2-cdef12_4232.xyz.afd`.

Em seguida, temos um `@`, que corresponde ao próprio caractere "arroba".

---

Agora temos a segunda parte do email, depois do `@`.

Primeiro temos `[A-Za-z0-9-]+` (uma ou mais letras/números/hífens).

Depois temos `(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*`, cuja lógica já vimos. Neste caso, significa "zero ou mais repetições de (ponto seguido de letras/números)". Isso serve para domínios como `algum.nome.comprido.com.br`: os trechos `.nome`, `.comprido` e `.com` correspondem a esta expressão.

Por fim, temos `(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})`. O quantificador `{2,}` significa "duas ou mais ocorrências". Portanto, esta expressão significa "ponto, seguido de 2 ou mais letras". Com isso, o domínio do email não pode terminar com `.a` ou `.b`, por exemplo, é preciso ter pelo menos duas letras.

Juntando as 3 expressões acima, temos o domínio do endereço de email, que pode ser desde `gmail.com` até endereços com vários sub-domínios, como `a333-bcd.abc.co.uk`.

---

## Sobre a validação de emails

Infelizmente, validar emails não é tão simples quanto parece. Há [regras demais](https://emailregex.com/email-validation-summary/) (cada parte do email tem um limite de tamanho, o domínio também pode ser um endereço IP, etc), e quanto mais precisa é a regex, mais complicada ela fica - [veja estes exemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373724), só para ter uma ideia. E quanto mais simples (ou menos complicada), maior a chance de falsos positivos.

A regex em questão, por exemplo, aceita emails como `-----abc@gmail.com` e `abc@-----abc.com` (veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/di9yFz/3) ela funcionando). Isso acontece porque usamos o hífen dentro dos colchetes e com quantificadores (uma ou mais ocorrências), por isso uma `String` com vários hífens é considerada válida.

Da mesma forma, no primeiro par de colchetes há um caractere `+`, e estes colchetes tem um quantificador `+` (uma ou mais ocorrências), então a regex considera que `+++++@abc.com` é um email válido (veja [aqui](https://ideone.com/3A3638)). *Tecnicamente, segundo a [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4), acredito que até seja, mas cabe a você decidir se seu sistema vai aceitar tais endereços*.

Outro problema é que ela não verifica os limites de tamanho de cada parte, nem aceita endereços IP no lugar do domínio (só para citar alguns casos). O fato é que, para cada regra a mais que você tenta colocar, mais difícil vai ficando: veja [neste link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) como a regex vai ficando cada vez mais complicada a cada vez que adicionamos uma regra.

No fim, você deve achar um meio-termo adequado para os seus casos de uso. Uma regex muito complicada pode virar um problema de manutenção futura (pegue uma das expressões dos links indicados; se já é difícil entender, imagine se tiver que modificar para adicionar um caso novo ou corrigir algum bug).

Considere os prós e contras: simplificar a regex significa abrir mão da precisão em troca de facilidade de manutenção (mas você passa a ter mais falsos positivos). E deixá-la mais precisa pode levar àqueles códigos complicados que todos têm medo de mexer.

O quão ruim será aceitar alguns emails inválidos (ou "estranhos", como `+++@---.com` ou `+_+_+@---.com`, ou ainda `+.-._-_@-.com`, todos considerados válidos pela regex em questão)? O quão ruim será não aceitar alguns casos válidos? E o que são casos válidos? `user@localhost` pode ser um caso válido, dependendo da situação, mas esta regex considera que é inválido. Algumas soluções pela internet consideram que a primeira parte (antes do `@`) também pode ter caracteres como `%`, `$` e `!` (que a sua regex não considera).

Para não aceitar os casos "estranhos" (ou ao menos minimizá-los), você pode alterar a regex para aceitar emails que comecem somente com letras, por exemplo, colocando esta condição logo após o `^`:

```
^[A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+.... (o resto é igual)
 ^^^^^^^^
```

Com isso, o primeiro caractere deve ser uma letra, e o restante pode ser "uma ou mais letras/números/hífens/*underlines*/sinal de mais" etc. A regex ainda vai aceitar `a+++@abc.com`, mas você pode adicionar uma [regra que não aceite dois `+` seguidos](https://regex101.com/r/8EXD13/1), etc (percebe o padrão "quanto mais regras, mais complicado fica"?).

Cabe a você testar, analisar seus casos de uso e decidir por um caminho. Regex é uma ferramenta extremamente poderosa (e na minha opinião, **muito** legal), mas [nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) para tudo.

Talvez uma solução mais simples seja separar em várias expressões (faz um `split` no `@` e verifica cada parte com uma regex diferente), o que pode ser mais fácil (de fazer, entender e manter) do que uma super-regex-monstruosa-que-faz-tudo. Outra solução é usar uma [lib externa](https://github.com/bbottema/email-rfc2822-validator).

---

<sup>Só lembrando que a regex não verifica se o email existe (se há uma conta para aquele usuário naquele servidor, se a conta está ativa, se alguém lê de fato os emails enviados para este endereço, etc).

Talvez no fim das contas seja mais fácil usar uma regex mais simples (que verifique algo que **pareça** um email, sem se preocupar com as regras mais complicadas) e em seguida você envia um email com um link de confirmação/ativação, como muitos sites costumam fazer.</sup>

---

Alguns tutoriais úteis sobre regex:

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html
- http://rexegg.com/

Comment: Muito obrigado hkotsubo! Ajudou demais.

Comment: @AndréFilipe De nada! Se vc achar que a resposta de fato responde/soluciona a pergunta, vc tem a opção de aceitá-la: veja [**aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Claro que vc não é obrigado a aceitar nenhuma resposta (apenas se vc achar que realmente respondeu à pergunta), mas isso serve para indicar a futuros visitantes que a resposta soluciona/responde ao que foi perguntado. E bons estudos com regex, pois é um assunto sem fim!

Comment: Perdão, eu até que votei na sua resposta na sexta-feira mesmo, porém, fechei o navegador rapidamente. Acredito que tenha sido por isso que não foi contabilizado!

Comment: @AndréFilipe Sem problemas!

Comment: Tenho um monte de sistemas que tenho que modificar depois de ler essa resposta.