# Função em JavaScript para validação de email não entra no else

Tags: javascript, regex, email, validação

Alguém pode me dizer porque essa função não consegue entrar no `else`?

Quando o email atende a função ele funciona normalmente só que quando não ele não faz nada, ou seja a função reconhece que a condição do `if` não é verdadeira, mas mesmo assim não entra no `else`:

```
function isValidEmail(email) {

    var regEmail = /^[\w.\+]+@\w+.\w{2,}(?:.\w{2})?$/gmi;

    email.replace(regEmail, function(match){
        if(match === email){
            alert('Email válido');
        }else{      
            alert('Email inválido');    
        }
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A função [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) serve para fazer substituições. No caso, ela usa a regex para buscar um trecho da string, que você pode substituir por outro (e este outro trecho pode ser inclusive o retorno de uma `function`). Usar esta `function` como forma de verificar se a regex deu *match* é como usar uma furadeira para apertar um parafuso (pode até funcionar às vezes, mas...)

*Como bem lembrado na [resposta do @Sam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348889/112052), a `function` só é chamada quando a regex encontra um match. Quando o email é inválido, ela sequer é executada, o que é mais um motivo para não "parafusar com a furadeira".*

No caso, você só quer saber se uma string corresponde à regex, então pode usar [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), que retorna `true` ou `false` (caso a string corresponda à regex ou não):

```js
let reg = /^[\w.\+]+@\w+.\w{2,}(?:.\w{2})?$/;

function isValidEmail(email){
  return reg.test(email);
}

console.log(isValidEmail('teste@email.com')); // true
console.log(isValidEmail('abc')); // false
```

O detalhe é que retirei as [flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) `g`, `m` e `i`, pois não são necessárias.

O `g` faz com que a regex [guarde o índice do último *match* encontrado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520853) e continue a partir daí (conforme [descrito na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Using_test()_on_a_regex_with_the_global_flag)), o que faz com que, se o primeiro *match* for encontrado, o segundo *match* seja feito a partir do final da string (já que a regex termina com `$`, que corresponde ao final da string). Como você sempre está buscando do início (`^`) ao fim (`$`) da string, não precisa desta opção.

O `m` ativa o modo *multiline*, mas acredito que não seja necessário porque um endereço de email não tem quebras de linhas.

E o `i` ativa o modo *case insensitive* (não diferencia maiúsculas e minúsculas). Mas como `\w` [já pega tanto letras maiúsculas como minúsculas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes), esta opção não é necessária.

Na verdade nem precisaria da `function`, você pode chamar `test` direto:

```js
let reg = /^[\w.\+]+@\w+.\w{2,}(?:.\w{2})?$/;

if (reg.test('teste@email.com')) {
  alert("Email válido");
} else {
  alert("Email inválido");
}
```

---

#### Sobre validação de emails com regex

Sobre o fato de usar regex para validar emails, eu falo em mais detalhes [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340617/112052).

Apenas para resumir, emails são [mais complexos do que parecem](https://emailregex.com/email-validation-summary/) e uma regex para validar qualquer email [é bem complicada](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

A sua regex, por exemplo, começa com `[\w.\+]`, o que significa que ela considera válidos os emails abaixo:

```js
let reg = /^[\w.\+]+@\w+.\w{2,}(?:.\w{2})?$/;

function isValidEmail(email){
  return reg.test(email);
}

console.log(isValidEmail('....@_.com')); // true
console.log(isValidEmail('...@__.11')); // true
console.log(isValidEmail('++_+@ab.__')); // true
```

Isso acontece porque os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): eles pegam qualquer caractere que esteja dentro deles. No caso, `[\w.\+]` significa:

- um [`\w`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes) (letras maiúsculas, minúsculas, números ou `_`), **ou**
- um ponto (`.`), **ou**
- um sinal de mais (`+`)

Em seguida há o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências", ou seja, `[\w.\+]+` aceita vários pontos ou vários `+`, ou vários `_` - [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/J7Gjml/1) exemplos deste trecho específico funcionando.

O mesmo vale para o restante da regex (principalmente o `\w`, que por aceitar `_`, acaba validando os casos acima).

Cabe a você decidir se vai conviver com estes falsos positivos, ou ir complicando sua regex cada vez mais, até chegar a [isso](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html):

```js
let reg = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/;

console.log(reg.test("teste@email.com")); // true
console.log(reg.test("abc")); // false
console.log(reg.test("....@_.com")); // false
console.log(reg.test("...@__.11")); // false
console.log(reg.test("++_+@ab.__")); // false
```

Ou [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181):

```js
let reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

console.log(reg.test("teste@email.com")); // true
console.log(reg.test("abc")); // false
console.log(reg.test("....@_.com")); // false
console.log(reg.test("...@__.11")); // false
console.log(reg.test("++_+@ab.__")); // false
```

Ou [isso](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) - essa eu confesso que nem tive coragem de testar, mas fica abaixo como referência:

```
(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ 
\t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\0
31]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\
](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+
(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:
(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\
r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)
*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+
|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r
\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031
]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](
?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?
:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?
:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?
:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?
[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] 
\000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|
\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>
@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"
(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?
:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[
\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-
\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(
?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;
:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([
^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"
.\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\
]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\
[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\
r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] 
\000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]
|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \0
00-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\
.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,
;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?
:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".
\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[
^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]
]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:,\s*(
?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[
\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?
:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|
\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:
[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\
]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["
()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>
@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,
;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?
(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".
\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[
"()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\
.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)?;\s*)
```

Comment: Essa ultima regex é hilariante :D até da medo

Comment: @Isac O pior é que no [link de onde tirei essa regex](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) é dito que "podem haver bugs". Eu é que não gostaria de corrigi-los :-)

Answer (score 1):

O *function* do replace não verifica condições a nível de validação porque a função só vai ser executada caso o replace tenha encontrado alguma ocorrência.

> Você pode usar condições `if` na function do replace?

Pode sim, mas apenas com o que foi encontrado, **e não com o que não foi encontrado**. Neste caso você pode fazer o que quiser com o que foi combinado no replace.

No exemplo abaixo, eu posso dizer se o email enviado para a função foi exatamente o esperado:

```js
function isValidEmail(email) {

    var regEmail = /^[\w.\+]+@\w+.\w{2,}(?:.\w{2})?$/gmi;

    return email.replace(regEmail, function(match){
        if(match === "nome@site.com"){
            return 'email válido';
        }else{      
            return 'Email inválido';
        }
    });     
}
console.log(isValidEmail("outro@site.com"));
console.log(isValidEmail("nome@site.com"));
```

No seu caso, se supostamente o email for inválido de acordo com a regex proposta (sem entrar no mérito da qualidade dessa regex, já bem atendida na [resposta do hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348859/8063)), o replace não será atendido e consequentemente a função nem será executada, porque a `function` do replace não funciona como um *callback*.

O replace não é usado para validações, mas para fazer substituições de acordo com combinações encontradas ([veja documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)) ou retornar algum tipo de tratamento dentro do que o replace encontrou.

Comment: É mesmo, esqueci de mencionar que a função só é executada se a regex encontrar um *match*. Muito bem lembrado :-)