# Função de validação de email

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, lista

Preciso de ajuda com este código, pois estou quebrando a cabeça e não consigo resolver.

Você primeiro digita o número de emails que deseja entrar com o `input`. Depois você digita os emails conforme o número que digitou antes.

Feito isto o programa verificará se passa na regra de expressões regulares, se passar adiciona em uma lista, senão não a adiciona e retorna a lista em ordem alfabética por final.

O código está assim por enquanto:

```
import re
def fun(s):
# return True if s is a valid email, else return False

s = emails
padrao = re.search(r'^[\w-]+@ [a-z\d]+\.[\w]{3}', s)

for i in range(len(s)):
if s[i] = padrao:
return True
else:
return False

def filter_mail(emails):
return list(filter(fun, emails))

if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
emails = []
for _ in range(n):
emails.append(input())

filtered_emails = filter_mail(emails)
filtered_emails.sort()
print(filtered_emails)
```

Comment: Por favor, corrija a indentação do seu código.

Comment: Em Python, identação não é opcional - é a sintaxe. Ao colar código aqui,use o botão `{}` para formatar preservando a identação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sobre a sua regex:

```
^[\w-]+@ [a-z\d]+\.[\w]{3}
```

Não sei se foi erro de digitação, mas veja que tem um espaço depois do `@`. Isso faz com que a expressão só valide emails que tem um espaço ali (como `user@ email.com`). Então a primeira coisa a fazer é retirar esse espaço.

Outro detalhe é que [atalho `\w`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-32) corresponde a letras, números e o caractere `_`. E no Python 3, por padrão, ele também corresponde a outras letras definidas no Unicode, como caracteres japoneses (e de vários outros idiomas), por exemplo:

```
import re

print(re.match(r'\w+', '鳥山.').group()) # imprime 鳥山
```

Se só quiser as letras do nosso alfabeto, pode usar a [flag `ASCII`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII), ou simplesmente use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` no lugar do `\w`:

```
# ambos imprimem "None", pois não encontram mais nenhum match
print(re.match(r'\w+', '鳥山.', flags=re.ASCII))
print(re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+', '鳥山.'))
```

Outro detalhe é que você usou `[\w-]+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências de um `\w` **ou** um `-`". E como `\w` também inclui o caractere `_`, isso quer dizer que a regex vai aceitar emails como `---__--@teste.com`.

Por fim, a parte depois da `@` termina com `\.[\w]{3}`. Antes de mais nada, `[\w]` é redundante, pois `\w` já representa um conjunto específico de caracteres, e colocá-lo entre colchetes é redundante (só faz sentido se você quiser colocar outras coisas junto com o `\w`, como você fez com `[\w-]`). Então pode trocar para simplesmente `\w{3}`.

Mas isso só vai aceitar domínios com exatamente 3 letras (excluindo o `.io`, `.br`, `.info`, entre muitos outros). E como `\w` também aceita números e `_`, esta regex aceita emails como `user@teste._1_`. Sem contar que não aceita emails que terminem com `com.br`, por exemplo.

Então você pode trocar tudo depois da `@` para algo como `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}`. Os parênteses `(?:` e `)` formam um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap). Basicamente estou agrupando a sub-expressão dentro deles, e o `?:` diz para a engine de regex não guardar o que for capturado (se não usar o `?:`, o que está entre parênteses é internamente guardado e pode ser obtido do *match* depois - mas como não quero isso, posso indicar na própria regex usando o `?:`).

O trecho acima garante que `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.` (letras, números ou `-` seguidos de um ponto), se repete por uma ou mais vezes (indicado pelo `+` depois dos parênteses). Isso garante que podemos ter emails `.com.br`, `.abc.def.etc.com` e por aí vai.

Por fim, temos 2 ou mais letras (`[a-zA-Z]{2,}`), o que garante que os domínios `.br` e `.info` (e qualquer outro, desde que tenha pelo menos duas letras) sejam aceitos.

Outra coisa que eu faria é acrescentar o [marcador `$`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), que delimita o final da string. Você já usou `^` (início da string), então usá-lo juntamente com `$` garante que toda a string terá somente o que está na expressão, e nada mais.

---

Enfim, fazer uma regex que valide corretamente 100% dos emails válidos é bem complicado. [Veja este artigo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), por exemplo, que começa com algo não muito complicado e termina com uma regex monstruosa.

Cabe a você decidir o quão complicada vai ser sua regex, pois quanto mais precisa (quanto mais casos especiais ela suporta), mais complicada e difícil de entender e manter ela vai ficando. Mas se há casos especiais que você não quer tratar (como endereços IP no domínio, ou `user@localhost`, por exemplo), então não compensa fazer algo tão complicado. Ache o equilíbrio entre a exatidão, complexidade e praticidade (e isso varia de um caso para outro).

Eu falo um pouco mais o uso de regex para validar emails [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340617/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327150/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348859/112052) (este último tem algumas opções no final, só não recomendo a última).

---

Independente da regex que você escolher, a verificação/filtro/ordenação pode ser feita assim:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'^[\w-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$')
emails = ['user@teste.com', 'nao sou email', 'fulano@abc123.com.br']


# filtra e ordena
filtered_emails = sorted(email for email in emails if r.match(email))
print(filtered_emails)
```

Usei a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052). 
A linha que cria `filtered_emails` é equivalente a:

```
filtered_emails = []
for email in emails:
    if r.match(email):
        filtered_emails.append(email)
filtered_emails.sort()
```

Em ambos os casos, a lista resultante é:

> ['fulano@abc123.com.br', 'user@teste.com']

---

Para ler a quantidade, sugiro validar se o que foi digitado é mesmo um número. Se não for, peça que o usuário tente novamente (encapsulei isso em uma função).

Por fim, também uso uma *list comprehension* para ler os emails e já colocá-los em uma lista.

O código completo:

```
import re

def le_quantidade():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input('quantidade de emails:'))
        except ValueError:
            # se não digitar um número, int() lança um ValueError
            print('Digite um número válido')

n = le_quantidade()
# lê os emails e coloca em uma lista
emails = [input('Digite um email:') for _ in range(n)]

r = re.compile(r'^[\w-]+@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$')
# filtra e ordena
filtered_emails = sorted(email for email in emails if r.match(email))
print(filtered_emails)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tá, mas por que você atribui emails para s na função `fun`? E qual o sentido do laço for? E essa expressão regular, está certa?

Acredito que o que você quer seja isso:

```
def fun(s):
    # return True if s is a valid email, else return False
    return re.search(r'^[\w]+@[\w]+\.[\w]{2,4}', s) != None
```

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado por todas as informações. Isso me ajudou a encontrar a regex que eu precisava. Mas só para ficar claro para futuras consultas alheias, a regex precisava ter essas regras:

> Valid email addresses must follow these rules:
>
> It must have the username@websitename.extension format type. 
>   The username can only contain letters, digits, dashes and underscores. 
>   The website name can only have letters and digits. 
>   The maximum length of the extension is 3.

O código final ficou assim:

```
import re
def fun(s):
padrao = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,3}$', s)

if padrao:
return True
else:
return False

def filter_mail(emails):
return list(filter(fun, emails))

if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
emails = []
for _ in range(n):
emails.append(input())

filtered_emails = filter_mail(emails)
filtered_emails.sort()
print(filtered_emails)
```

Removi aquele laço for, pois ele estava percorrendo um único elemento, não um array de elementos, como eu havia pensado