# Regex em Python Validar E-mail

Tags: python

Bom dia!

```
valid = re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z\.a-zA-Z]{1,3}$', email)
```

Eu tenho essa expressão regular, e existem algumas regras para retornar os e-mails corretos, são 8 testes, e to conseguindo passar em 7 deles, porém me da um erro em 1 teste, ele espera que retorne @yahoo.com.br porém só passa o e-mail: @yahoo.com

Já tentei algumas alterações mas não resolveu muito porque passa nesse teste e falha nos outros. 
O comprimento máximo da extensão é 1,2 e 3 caracteres.

Obrigada!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Entendendo a expressão que você escreveu:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z\.a-zA-Z]{1,3}$
 |_____________| |__________|  |____________________| 
        |             |                  |
        |             |                  +-> (3) Buscará o resto do e-mail
        |             |
        |             +-> (2) Buscará o conteúdo após o @ até encontrar o primeiro .
        |
        +-> (1) Buscará o conteúdo antes do @
```

Para o e-mail `fulano@yahoo.com.br` teríamos:

1. A primeira parte pegaria `fulano`;
2. A segunda parte pegaria `yahoo`;
3. A terceira parte **deveria** pegar `com.br`;

O problema está na terceira parte, onde deveria pegar o valor `com.br`, mas você limitou a quantidade de caracteres entre 1 e 3:

```
[a-zA-Z\.a-zA-Z]{1,3}
```

Isso explica porque funciona para `yahoo.com`, pois `com` tem apenas 3 letras, mas para `yahoo.com.br` não porque `com.br` possui 6 letras, falhando na expressão regular.

Você precisa mesmo limitar o número de caracteres na última parte?

Comment: Olá Anderson, obrigada pela resposta!
Então no caso eu preciso limitar o final até 3 dígitos, teria como fazer isso pra duas extensões? por exemplo limitar um email (.com.br) e o (.com) também para até 3 dígitos?

Comment: @Carol Sugiro que veja a pergunta duplicada, [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365489/112052) tem uma sugestão do que colocar na regex depois do `@` para aceitar `.com.br`. E também tem algumas considerações a mais, além de links para outras perguntas relacionadas (e com outras sugestões de regex também)

Comment: obrigada a todos, no final a expressão ficou assim (r'^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@([a-z0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{2,3})+$' e deu certo