# Expressão regular para validação de e-mail com REGEXP_LIKE no Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Estou a tentar introduzir uma validação adicional na minha expressão regular em Oracle 11G utilizando o `REGEXP_LIKE`.

Pretendo que a expressão detecte dois underscores consecutivos mas, que ignore se forem intercalados. Só quero fazer esta validação na parte local do domínio, ou seja, depois do arroba e antes do primeiro ponto `.`.

**Ex:**

- blablabla@sapo_gmail.com será um e-mail válido;
- blablabla@stack_sapo_gmail.com será um e-mail válido;
- blablabla@sapo__gmail.com será um **e-mail rejeitado**.

A expressão que tenho neste momento é a seguinte:

```
'^[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]*[.]{1,1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}$'
```

Query que utilizo para validar:

```
WITH T1 AS (

SELECT 'blablabla@sapo_gmail.com' EMAIL FROM DUAL
UNION

SELECT 'blablabla@stack_sapo_gmail.com' EMAIL FROM DUAL
UNION

SELECT 'blablabla@sapo__gmail.com' EMAIL FROM DUAL
UNION

SELECT ' ' EMAIL FROM DUAL
)

SELECT EMAIL,ROWNUM

FROM T1 

WHERE 1=1

AND NOT (REGEXP_LIKE (EMAIL,'^[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]*[.]{1,1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}$')

AND LENGTH (EMAIL) > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, dá para simplificar um pouco sua expressão. No lugar de `a-zA-Z0-9` é possível usar simplesmente `[:alnum:]`.

E `[.]{1,1}` significa "no mínimo 1 e no máximo 1 ponto final" - ou seja, o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{1,1}` é redundante e pode ser omitido. O uso dos colchetes (também chamado de "[classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)") é útil quando há mais de um caractere possível (como você faz para `[a-zA-Z]`, por exemplo). Quando há apenas um caractere, não é necessário usar colchetes.

E o ponto pode ser escrito como `\.` (o ponto sozinho tem significado especial - equivale a "[qualquer caractere (exceto quebras de linha)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)" - e para que ele seja considerado apenas o caractere "ponto", devemos escapá-lo com `\`).

Por fim, testar o `LENGTH` do campo também não é necessário. A regex já começa com `[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+` (o `+` no final significa "**uma ou mais** ocorrências de determinada coisa", o que já garante que vai ter pelo menos um caractere). E isso se repete por mais de uma vez, além de ter o `@` e o `{2,}` (duas ou mais ocorrências), o que já garante pelo menos mais alguns caracteres. Se o campo tiver menos caracteres que o necessário, a regex falha, então é desnecessário verificar o tamanho do mesmo.

---

Outro ponto é sobre o uso de regex para validar emails. O assunto é bem amplo e há muitas possibilidades. Na prática, você deve encontrar um equilíbrio entre a complexidade da regex e a corretude dos resultados. Se para os seus dados uma regex mais simples já resolve, não há problema nenhum. Mas se uma regex simples demais acaba aceitando emails inválidos, também não adianta muito.

A sua regex, por exemplo, começa com `[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+`, o que quer dizer que aceitará emails como `_+--1-@gmail.com`. Cabe a você decidir se isso é aceitável ou não (dependendo dos dados que serão consultados, pode ser que não faça diferença, então cada caso é um caso).

Enfim, sobre o uso de regex para validar emails, tem mais algumas coisas  [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340617/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327150/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365489/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348859/112052) (este último tem algumas opções de regex no final, só não recomendo a última). [Este artigo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) também tem algumas opções, e veja como a regex começa mais ou menos simples e vai ficando cada vez mais complicada.

---

Independente da regex que você escolher, sugiro que faça sua query usando duas expressões: uma para verificar o email e outra para verificar que não há dois `_` seguidos. Exemplo:

```
WITH T1 AS (
  SELECT 'blablabla@sapo_gmail.com' EMAIL FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'blablabla@stack_sapo_gmail.com.br' EMAIL FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'blablabla@sapo__gmail.com' EMAIL FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'doisunderscores@depois.doprimeiro__ponto.com' EMAIL FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT ' ' EMAIL FROM DUAL
)
SELECT EMAIL,ROWNUM
FROM T1 
WHERE
REGEXP_LIKE (EMAIL,'^[[:alnum:]_+-]+[[:alnum:]._+-]*[[:alnum:]_+-]+@[[:alnum:]_+-]+(\.[[:alnum:]_+-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$')
AND
NOT REGEXP_LIKE(EMAIL, '^[^@]+@[^_.]*__[^.]*\..*$')
```

Com isso, a primeira regex verifica se o email é válido (e você pode continuar usando a sua ou mudar para alguma das sugeridas nos links que passei acima). Já a segunda regex verifica se há dois `_` seguidos depois do `@`.

Eu usei uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), delimitado por `[^` e `]`. Isso funciona como o oposto de `[]`: enquanto `[a-z]` é "uma letra de `a` a `z`", `[^a-z]` é "qualquer caractere que **não** seja uma letra de `a` a `z`". No caso, a regex significa:

- `^`: início da string
- `[^@]+`: um ou mais caracteres que não são `@`
- `@`: o próprio caractere "arroba"
- `[^_.]*`: zero ou mais caracteres que não são `_` nem `.` (garantindo que só vou pegar os `__` antes do primeiro ponto)
- `__`: dois caracteres `_` seguidos (que também pode trocar por `_{2}`, se achar que fica mais legível)
- `[^.]*`: zero ou mais caracteres que não são `.`
- `\..*`: o próprio caractere ponto (`\.`) seguido de "qualquer coisa" (`.*`)
- `$`: final da string

Ou seja, a regex verifica se há dois `_` seguidos em alguma posição depois do `@`, desde que seja antes do primeiro ponto. Algumas classes de caracteres negados talvez sejam redundantes, pois a primeira regex já verificou o formato, mas eu prefiro deixar bem explícito o que estou verificando.

No caso, os emails retornados serão `blablabla@sapo_gmail.com`, `blablabla@stack_sapo_gmail.com.br` e `doisunderscores@depois.doprimeiro__ponto.com`. Veja este exemplo no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/06de4/27/0).

---

Em vez de `[:alnum:]`, também é possível usar o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w`, que é equivalente a `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Repare que a diferença entre `\w` e `[:alnum:]` é que `\w` também considera o caractere `_`.

O único detalhe é que no Oracle [não é possível usar `\w` (ou qualquer outro desses atalhos) dentro dos colchetes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39904854). Normalmente - em outras linguagens/engines - é possível fazer `[\w+-]`, por exemplo, que seria equivalente a `[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]`, mas no Oracle o `\w` não funciona dentro dos colchetes. Mas dá para fazer algo semelhante usando [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html): `(\w|[+-])` - o caractere `|` significa **ou**, então esta regex seria "um `\w` **ou** um `[+-]` (que por sua vez, significa 'um `+` ou um `-`')".

Sendo assim, a query também poderia ser assim:

```
WITH T1 AS (
  SELECT 'blablabla@sapo_gmail.com' EMAIL FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'blablabla@stack_sapo_gmail.com.br' EMAIL FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'blablabla@sapo__gmail.com' EMAIL FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'doisunderscores@depois.doprimeiro__ponto.com' EMAIL FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT ' ' EMAIL FROM DUAL
)
SELECT EMAIL,ROWNUM
FROM T1 
WHERE
REGEXP_LIKE (EMAIL,'^(\w|[+-])+(\w|[.+-])*(\w|[+-])+@(\w|[+-])+(\.(\w|[+-])+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$')
AND
NOT REGEXP_LIKE(EMAIL, '^[^@]+@[^_.]*__[^.]*\..*$')
```

O resultado é o mesmo da anterior (veja no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/06de4/29/0)).