# Validar email em memória JAVA

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

No java, como faço pra verificar se o String que o usuário digitou possui o caractere "@" ou se termina com ".com" ou ".br" pra validar o email em memória ?

Comment: A pergunta linkada é com javascript, mas basta usar a classe `java.util.regex.Pattern` que dá para adaptar isso ao java facilmente.

Comment: Ainda sobre o uso de regex para validar emails, tem algumas coisas  [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340617/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327150/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365489/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348859/112052) (este último link tem algumas opções no final, só não recomendo a última regex). Para o uso de regex especificamente em Java, sugiro [este tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: Você pode usar a regex `\w+(@)\w+(.)\w+`, que verifica a existência de um "@" e um "." e caracteres entre elas.

Answer (score 2):

Para saber se a string possui o caractere `@`, você pode utilizar o `contains`:

```
String teste = "abc@s";
if (teste.contains("@")) {
    System.out.println("existe o caractere @ na string");
} else {
    System.out.println("não existe o caractere @ na string");
}
```

Para saber se a string termina com `.com` ou `.br` você pode utilizar uma `substring`:

```
String teste = "teste.com";
if (teste.substring(teste.length() - 4, teste.length()).equals(".com")) {
     System.out.println("a string acaba com .com");
} else {
     System.out.println("a string nao acaba com .com");
}

if (teste.substring(teste.length() - 3, teste.length()).equals(".br")) {
    System.out.println("a string acaba com .br");
} else {
    System.out.println("a string não acaba com .br");
}
```

Comment: Em vez de `substring`, também é possível usar [`endsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-)