# Extraindo endereços de email de uma página web usando expressões regulares em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

O que eu fiz:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from re import findall

def emails(url):
    content = urlopen(url).read().decode()

    #print(content)
    padrao = "(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)"

    mails = findall(padrao, content)
    print(mails)


url = "http://www.cdm.depaul.edu"
emails(url)
```

Aparentemente a expressão regular `(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)` está correta mas a saída do programa está sendo uma lista vazia. O que está acontecendo?

Comment: Bom, a resposta abaixo já diz que o problema era o `^` e o `$`, que indicam o início e fim da string (ou seja, a regex só ia achar algo se a string tivesse **somente** o email). Sobre o uso de regex para validar emails, tem algumas coisas  [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340617/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327150/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365489/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348859/112052) (este último link tem algumas opções no final, só não recomendo a última regex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a seguinte expressão regular

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/
```

logo seu código fica:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from re import findall

def emails(url):
    content = urlopen(url).read().decode()

    #print(content)
    padrao = "([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)"

    mails = findall(padrao, content)
    print(mails)


url = "http://www.cdm.depaul.edu"
emails(url)
```

saída:

```
['admission@cdm.depaul.edu', 'advising@cdm.depaul.edu', 'wwwfeedback@cdm.depaul.edu', 'wwwfeedback@cdm.depaul.edu']
```

As âncoras em expressões regulares determinam uma posição antes, depois ou entre os caracteres. Eles podem ser usados ​​para "ancorar" a correspondência de regex em uma determinada posição. O sinal de intercalação ^ corresponde à posição antes do primeiro caractere na sequência. A aplicação da regex "^a" em "abc" corresponde a "a". Por sua vez a regex "^b" não corresponde em "abc", porque "b" não pode ser correspondido logo após o início da string, correspondido pelo caractere ^.
Para testar expressões regulares de uma forma intuitiva recomendo o seguinte site **https://rubular.com/**

Comment: Conseguiria me explicar o que tinha de errado na regex?

Comment: As âncoras em expressões regulares determinam uma posição antes, depois ou entre os caracteres. Eles podem ser usados ​​para "ancorar" a correspondência de regex em uma determinada posição. O sinal de intercalação ^ corresponde à posição antes do primeiro caractere na sequência. A aplicação da regex "^a" em "abc" corresponde a "a". Por sua vez a regex "^b" não corresponde em "abc", porque "b" não pode ser correspondido logo após o início da string, correspondido pelo caractere ^. A mesma lógica para o caractere $ só que para o final da frase. Espero ter ajudado. @EdS