# Alterar Regex para validar dominio de email do Java to Oracle sql

Tags: javascript, regex, oracle

Preciso de ajuda para alterar a Regex abaixo para validar domínios de email numa base ORACLE
de acordo com a norma RFC 5322, garantindo que os critérios abaixo devem ser respeitados.

Regras de domínio de email a respeitar:

1. deve começar por letra ou dígito e ter um comrimento entre 1 e 63 caractéres.
2. pode conter maiúsculas e minúsculas do alfabeto latino (A a Z e a a z).
3. pode conter digitos 0 to 9, desde que o domínio (top-level) não seja composto só por números.
4. pode conter hyphen -, desde que não seja nem o primeiro nem o último caractére, e não apareçam consecutivos.
5. deve aceitar 2 ou mais caractéres no TLD. (abc@t.com não válido, mas abc@tt.com é válido).

Descobri na internet a regex abaixo que funciona perfeitamente e cumpre as regras que enunciei em Javascript. O problema é que o ORACLE não suporta look-ahead/-behind.

```
@(?:(?=[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.)[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)*\.){1,8}[A-Z]{2,63}$
```

Será que alguém me pode ajudar, por favor, a efectuar as modificações necessárias para esta regex
funcione em Oracle SQL?

Muito obrigado

Comment: Fazer uma regex que seja totalmente compatível com a RFC 5322 é bem complicado: https://emailregex.com/ - de qualquer forma, você pode retirar o lookahead e validar o tamanho do campo separadamente, com `LENGTH` (e `SUBSTR` para pegar o trecho depois do `@`)

Comment: E só pra constar, essa regex aceita `abc@t.com`: https://regex101.com/r/bo46A6/1/ :-) Mas enfim, talvez seja melhor ler os emails do banco e tratá-los fora, usando alguma linguagem que suporte lookahead (ou que tenha alguma outra lib dedicada para validar emails, já que, como vc viu, com regex é bem mais complicado)

Comment: Muito obrigado hkotsubo. Seguindo o teu conselho onde efectuar o teste separadamente, podes por favor ajudar a alterar esta regex '@([A-Z0-9]+(-[A-Z0-9]+)*\.){1,8}[A-Z]{2,63}$', de modo a só aceitar um ponto depois de cada 2 caractéres? (abc@t.com não válido; abc@tt.com.br é válido)

Comment: Um jeito seria `@(?:(?:[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)*){2,}\.){1,8}[A-Z]{2,63}$`. Mas como eu disse, talvez seja melhor fazer fora do banco. As linguagens de programação costumam ter mais recursos para esse tipo de validação (seja com regex, seja com libs que validam isso). Fazer tudo em uma única regex é complicado, sempre vai ter um caso "estranho" que ela não pega. Veja uns exemplos [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/340617/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327150/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365489/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348859/112052)